# I would like to make a v-for loop on an image with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, vue.js

I would like to make a boncle with v-for but before I would like to make sure that my images are displayed but when I mount my code my console makes me understand not found my image.

the rendering of my template

```
<template>
    <article>
       <h3>{{ titre }}</h3>
       <img :src="`./../images/${source}`" :[attributeClass]="classe"  alt="image site">
       <p class="mt-4 lead">{{ texte }} </p>
       <a :[attributeName]="liens" target="blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir le site</a>
     </article>
</template>
```

My script

```
export default {
    data(){
      return  {
         attributeName: 'href',
         attributeClass: 'class',
         classe: 'img-fluid w-50 shadow border rounded-lg border-secondary',
         source: 'germain.png',
         titre: 'Premiére Version',
         texte: 'C'était la première version de mon site, dans les balbutiements',
         liens: 'https://alain-germain.fr/'    
       }
     }
}
```

I search by all means of the poster but do not pass, my image is put away in this way "assets / images / image.png". I work with symfony.

Comment: Try using the path `./images/${source}`. Double dot is meant to go up one level, so you shouldn't use single dot with double dot.

Comment: Code highlighting shows that your javascript is invalid. The quote in `C'était` terminates the string and should cause an error.

Comment: I also tried to improve the layout of your question a little bit, but I am unsure what a "boncle" is. Google Translate suggests that it is French, which seems correct looking at the rest of your question, but does not offer a translation.